# Automate CSV write from Netsuite Dataset or Workbook via SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have several long running datasets and workbooks that I would like to be able to publish to the file cabinet and make public to our team.  We have a number of scripts that convert saved searches and some that use the n/query methods to query the database directly and then writes that to csv.  I'm not sure how to bridge the gap between the saved search version and the dataset/workbook version.  The code below are for saved search and suite_ql respectively.  They are both functional, though the query in the latter is a dummy.

```
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ScheduledScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
define(['N/task'],
/**
* @param {record} record
* @param {search} search
*/
function(task) {
var FILE_ID = 32254; 
var SEARCH_ID = 1304;
function execute(scriptContext) {
var searchTask = task.create({
taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH
});
searchTask.savedSearchId = SEARCH_ID;
searchTask.fileId = FILE_ID;
var searchTaskId = searchTask.submit();
}
return {
execute: execute
};

});
```

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType ScheduledScript
* @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
define(['N/task'],
/**
* @param {record} record
* @param {search} search
*/
function(task) {
var FILE_ID = 38961; 
function execute(scriptContext) {
    var mySuiteQLTask = task.create({
        taskType: task.TaskType.SUITE_QL
    });
    mySuiteQLTask.query = 'SELECT * from item';



    mySuiteQLTask.fileId = FILE_ID;
    var mySuiteQLTaskId = mySuiteQLTask.submit();
    }
    return {
    execute: execute
};

});
```

Comment: What's the actual issue? Both of those look like they should work.

Comment: Both of these do work.  I've seen it referenced elsewhere(reddit) that it is possible to do this operation on Analytics Workbooks and/or Datasets but I can glean enough from the documentation to make it work.  Those scripts use Tasktype.Search and  TaskType.SUITE_QL respectively, however, there is not a TaskType associated with either of those objects so I'm not sure how to generate the request.